# Fastest way to generate n combinations in python

Tags: python, performance, combinations, python-itertools

I have an array of 10 elements and am looking for the **fastest** way to randomly generate n combinations of size m in Python with those 10 elements.

I have to do that for all possible sizes of the combinations (m goes from 1 to the number of elements) and n also varies, it increases when the number of combination possible increases.

```
For example if my input array is: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
for n = 4 and m = 3 the output should be:

(e, b, c)
(i, a, d)
(g, j, e)
(i, f, e)

There can't be twice the same element in one permutation.
```

I am aware of the itertool function that generates all combination of a given size, but I only need n combinations, not all. So I am not sure that using itertools is the fastest solution for my problem (since I have then to select randomly n combinations among all those generated).

Comment: Can you clarify the question on the task description? Are you looking for permutations of a single array of a given size or combinations of multiple arrays of given sizes?

Comment: I added more details in the post @playerJX1

Comment: Thx for your replies, I added an example, and your assumptions are right @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: I wrote it here: "(m goes from 1 to the number of elements)", but an example is definitely clearer

Comment: Just shuffle the list and extract in groups of m. n*m must be equal to len(lst)

Comment: fastest *might* be precomputing all combinations and randomly sampling those

Comment: "there can't be twice the same element in one permutation"-- does that mean `(i, a, i)` is not ok?

Answer (score 2):

Unique Element

For this approach make sure to not pass `m`(sample size) value greater than the `array`(population size) size. Or you can add an if statement to check the `m` value.

```
import random

def generate_combinations(array, m, n):
    """Generate n random combinations of size m"""
    if m > len(array): # Changing the m value to array length if it is greater than length of array
        m = len(array)
    return [random.sample(array, k=m) for _ in range(n)] # for unique element

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 5  # Number of combinations
m = 10

print(generate_combinations(array, m, n))
```

Sample Output

```
[[8, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9],
 [9, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2, 10, 3, 4, 5],
 [8, 3, 7, 10, 6, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4],
 [10, 8, 9, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 1, 3],
 [5, 4, 1, 7, 10, 6, 3, 9, 8, 2]]
```

---

For non-unique element

```
import random

def generate_combinations(array, m, n):
    """Generate n random combinations of size m using list comprehension"""
    return [random.choices(array, k=m) for _ in range(n)]

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 5  # Number of combinations
m = 10

print(generate_combinations(array, m, n))
```

Sample Output

```
[[9, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 1],
 [2, 6, 10, 3, 6, 1, 7, 6, 2, 4],
 [1, 9, 7, 9, 8, 2, 10, 1, 1, 7],
 [10, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 1, 4, 1],
 [9, 3, 3, 5, 9, 4, 9, 8, 10, 6]]
```

---

or you can use `numpy` (**Unique**)

```
import numpy as np
def generate_combinations(array, m, n):
    if m> len(array):
        m = len(array)
    return [np.random.choice(array, (1, m), replace=False).tolist()[0] for _ in range(n)]

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 5  # Number of combinations
m = 10

print(generate_combinations(array, m, n))
```

Sample Output

```
[[6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5],
 [8, 5, 2, 10, 7, 3, 9, 4, 1, 6],
 [8, 1, 4, 10, 3, 6, 9, 7, 2, 5],
 [7, 4, 8, 5, 3, 9, 6, 10, 1, 2],
 [1, 8, 7, 3, 9, 2, 5, 4, 10, 6]]
```

Comment: Is this the fastest way?

Comment: Seems to be the most reasonable approach

Answer (score 1):

A comment on the existing answers.

*Disclaimer, as originally noted in a comment, my preconception was that codester_09 was the most straightforward and likely the most efficient.*

First the incorrect answers:

- [playerJX1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76610703/16343464): this is only generating the first N combinations of items, which is already available using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).
- [DarkKnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76610698/16343464): this doesn't allow to reuse the same item in **different** combinations, which is not part of the expected logic
- [Pierre Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4098049/pierre-alex): the code is incorrect and won't run (improper use of `combinations` and `shuffle`)

Now a timing of the two correct answers [codester_09](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17507911/codester-09) and [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie).

I generated random input lists, and set `m` and `n` to be 1/100th and 1/10th of the length of the input, then computed the total running time and plotted with [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot).

I had to wrap selbie's `makeRandomPermutation` function to repeat it `n` times:

```
def selbie(array):
    m = len(array)//100
    n = len(array)//10
    return [makeRandomPermutation(array, m) for _ in range(n)]
```

[image]

The winner is the simple: `[random.sample(array, k=m) for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: I think `np.random.choice` is  winner because on my side this is the output of `timeit` module. (if you want I can share the code of `timeit` program). 

`n=1000, m=10000, array size=100000`
`random.sample: 0.03557316000005813 seconds`
`random.choices: 0.011317680000138353 seconds`
`np.random.choice: 0.004908399999840185 seconds`

Comment: And this is my [graph](https://upcdn.io/W142hJk/raw/demo/4mL96Nv326.png).

Comment: @codester_09 but the choice and numpy approaches are not valid for the question, they will produce duplicates or prevent reusing an item across combinations (which is clearly not wanted given the example).

Comment: @mozway - Can you rebench with the minor updates I made? I adjusted to generate `n` permutations without cloning the list each time. And the shuffled only the first `m` elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `more-itertools` library has some useful functions that can index into a set of combinations at high speed.

```py
from more_itertools import combination_index, nth_combination
import random
import pprint

digit_range = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
combination_size = 3
sample_size = 10
domain = digit_range * combination_size
last_combination = tuple(digit_range[-1] * combination_size)
last_index = combination_index(last_combination, domain)
sample_indexes = random.sample(range(0, last_index + 1), sample_size)
sample = [
    nth_combination(domain, combination_size, index)
    for index
    in sample_indexes
]
pprint.pprint(sorted(sample), indent=4)
```

Results:

```
python rand_combinations.py 
[   ('b', 'e', 'i'),
    ('b', 'f', 'a'),
    ('b', 'i', 'j'),
    ('c', 'j', 'd'),
    ('d', 'j', 'h'),
    ('f', 'g', 'b'),
    ('g', 'b', 'c'),
    ('g', 'f', 'g'),
    ('h', 'a', 'd'),
    ('i', 'c', 'g')]
```

The code above selects thousands of random, unique combinations in a second or so.

Method:

1. construct the last possible combination
2. get its index using `more_itertools.combination_index()`
3. get a sample of integer indexes between 0 and the last index using `random.sample()`
4. convert the indexes to their corresponding combinations using `more_itertools.nth_combination()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` will be the fastest on every platforms because of its efficient implementation. Combinations are not computed upfront but only when iterating.

Doing this should give you the best results :

```py
from itertools import combinations, islice

#: Generates an iterator for 10 elements among all combinations
#: Note that it is not random at all
input_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
m_size = 3

all_combinations = combinations(input_data, m_size)
subset = islice(all_combinations, 10)


#: To add randomness
from random import shuffle

shuffle(input_data)

all_combinations = combinations(input_data, m_size)
subset = islice(all_combinations, 10)
```

Comment: 1- your code is incorrect (you haven't tested it), combinations is missing a parameter and shuffle is in place (thus has no output). 2- the logic is flawed, this will generate a random order for the first list but all subsequent one will be determined from that. Not a good approach IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll edit the proposed answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a small list, this seems as good as anything else:

```
def shuffle(items, m=len(items)):
   for i in range(m):
       j = math.floor(random.random() * len(items))
       items[i],items[j] = items[j],items[i]

def makeRandomPermutations(items, n, m):
   clone = items[0:]
   permutations=[]
   for i in range(n):
       shuffle(clone,m)
       permutations.append(clone[0:m])
   return permutations
```

Example:

```
>>> items=['a','b','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
>>> perms = makeRandomPermutations(items,4,3)
>>> for p in perms:
...      print(p)

['b', 'i', 'j']
['a', 'g', 'e']
['e', 'j', 'a']
['a', 'd', 'h']
>>>
```

Comment: @DarkKnight - lol, I hard never heard of random.shuffle until now.

Comment: @DarkKnight By being biased (for two different reasons even).

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [this solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/) which originally gives all combinations at time complexity O(N^2). This is the modified version:

```
cnt=0
def printCombination(arr, size, m,n):
    global cnt
    data = [0]*m
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0,
                    size - 1, 0, m,n)
 
def combinationUtil(arr, data, start,
                    end, index, m, n):
    global cnt
    if (index == m):
        for j in range(m):
            print(data[j], end = " ");
        print()
        cnt+=1
        return

    i = start;
    while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= m - index and cnt<n):
        data[index] = arr[i]
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1,
                        end, index + 1, m, n)
        i += 1
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
m = 3
size = len(arr)
n= 5
printCombination(arr, size, m, n)
```

This will print all combinations if needed but isn't completely random (not sure if that's you want or not)

Comment: This isn't what is asked for, this just reimplements `itertools.combinations`